Configure Ubuntu to not modify at all the RTC
When using a double boot Windows + Linux Ubuntu, there is a well-known issue that one uses the RTC-stored-time as local time, and the other uses UTC. See linked (not duplicate) questions like Ubuntu 18.04 cannot set hardware clock as local time.
After a sequence of Windows boot, Linux boot, Windows boot, there is a -1 hour shift stored in the RTC.
There are solutions like:
sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock

But more generally, how to ask Ubunu to not modify at all the value stored in the real time clock chip (RTC)? Also, which process is responsible for modifying the RTC-stored-value?
(i.e. Ubuntu should not change any value in RTC, never, even if there is a daylight saving time change, etc. this will be done outside of Ubuntu)
Notes:

even if sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock works, my question is more general: I'd like to understand why in the first place Ubuntu does modify the RTC if we don't ask it to do it. After a Win boot, Ubuntu boot, Win boot cycle, we see a shift of 1 hour. Why does this happen in the first place?

my question is in fact OS-agnostic, not related to Windows: let's say we have (1) Ubuntu  + (2) a second OS (could be any OS in fact). I would like that Ubuntu does not modify anything about RTC, it should not modify the RTC-stored-value. How to do this?



The answers in the linked question do work.  Windows is the one automatically adjusting the bios clock; Ubuntu only does that when you tell it the system to do that.  2 OS's need to act the  same for this to work; in the linked anwers there is  a method to fix this in windows That one does what you want

@Rinzwind See my edited question at the end, my question is more generally, why does this happen?

because windows does it in a stupid way ;-) The best fix is to set windows to do this correctly.

@Rinzwind No, my question is in fact OS-agnostic, not related to Windows ;) I have (1) Ubuntu  + (2) a second OS (could be any OS in fact). I would like that Ubuntu does not modify anything about RTC, it should not modify the RTC-stored-value. How to do this?

It's unlikely to be any other OS, since most other commonly used OSs also use UTC for RTC. Windows is pretty much the only common exception. At this point it's like asking the rest of the world to use imperial units for space travel.

@muru the question is just: why is the RTC-stored-value even modified at all after a Linux boot sequence? Is it possible to avoid any modification?

"Why" is a meaningless question. Somebody might have decided that's the most useful thing to do for most users; after all there's a well known adjustment to make Windows use UTC and people don't generally care about other imaginary OSs. As to avoid it: sure, have your imaginary alternate OS run a VM presenting a virtual RTC to Linux.

@muru Independently of any other OS, respecting the UNIX KISS philosophy, we should be able to turn off the feature that modifies the value stored in the RTC during a Linux boot, if we want to. Which process is reponsible for modifying the time stored in RTC? If we cannot answer this question we don't truly understand how things work (me included!) and that's what I want to understand :)

@Basj by the UNIX KISS philosophy, the devs have kept it simple - for them: more configurables => more complexity. See also: http://www.islinuxaboutchoice.com/ Systemd itself will update the clock is if it is too far behind, other than that systemd-timedated would probably also do it, not sure what else.

@muru This is probably the answer to this question (I'll accept it): systemd, systemd-timedated, and possibly others are the processes responsible for modifying the RTC-stored-value.

I guess if one disables the ntp and/or chrony module in Ubuntu, it will
just propagate time according to the battery-supported clock while
the computer is halted --- this will diverge at rates of some 10^-6 from actual
time and stop working at all if the battery-pack becomes old, which means one needs to enter the bios at each boot to adjust the time value (and another side effect all certificates concerning dhcp etc will stop to work because clocks differ too much).

@R.J.Mathar Yes this would be fine, I want to prevent this OS to touch anything related to time, and let the other OS do it (double boot scheme).
